# Android CONFLICTING_PROVIDER error when updating app from AIR to Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, air, android-manifest, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm updating my game from Adobe AIR to Unity.
I set the old AIR certificate in Unity, set the same package name (air.com..) and set bigger version..but when trying to update the app from GooglePlay store I get 505 error and from ADB I get INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER error.

When I uninstall the old version first and then update - it is ok.
How can I fix the updating ? I guess manifest changes has to be made to match the old air app configuration ?

**Edit:**
The problems turns to be facebook sdk:

```
<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider... />
```

But this means that android interprets the app as separate one, but it not.
The package id is the same, the app name is the same, the version is higher. **What else should I change in the manifest ?**

Comment: Did you get a resolution to this issue? We are in the same position.

Comment: You can use WebView facebook integration. It does not require any permissions or minimum android version. It always works, but users have to enter their password the first time (instead of using this approach and authenticate with FB app installed).

Comment: I solved this long time ago and don't really remember the fix. Try to see all other facebook manifest additions and uses (sharing, posting..).
Also check if you have another installed app of yours that uses the same FB content provider